# How to return Data from multiple tables in DAL layer with one-to-many relationship using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have one customer table and orders table with one-to-many relationship in database and my requirement is to get the corresponding list of orders for each customers.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frNN2.png)

Here is the list of orders done for customerid = 1

I am able to do it by multiple cycle call of database(For example - first i collected the list of customers and then for each customers i collected their orders list in corresponding listDTO and finally returned the list of customer with oders DTO to the BAL Layer.

I think this is not good to call multiple time to call database to get the data. Is there any efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Use the [JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374749/ado-net-sql-query-join), Luke.

Comment: You may post your some code here ... Otherwise in SQL you may do below ... You may add some 

    `Select  C.*, O.* FROM Customers C
    Left Join Orders O on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID`

Comment: Thanks, join can be helpful but in case of one-to-many relationship i will get multiple records for each customers and after that i need to run loop to create Required DTO. am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

While you can do a join, like you said you will get back multiple records for the each order duplicating customer information, which you code will have to de-duplicate.

I like to use SqlDataReader's support for multiple result sets to make this easier.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223698(v=vs.110).aspx

So you SQL will look something like this:

```
--Assume that @CustomerId is a parameter (always use parameters!)
SELECT CustomerId, CustomerName
  FROM Customer
 WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId

SELECT OrderId, OrderDate --all your order columns
  FROM Orders
 WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
```

Then in your ADO.Net code:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteDataReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //read first result set
    }

    reader.NextResult();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //read secondresult set
    }
}
```

Or even better, use the async versions of ExecuteDataReader, Read, NextResult :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Cleverguy25. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2016 this can be done very nicely with JSON path query
to return a hierarchical structure of JSON which can then be deserialized into your objects, or possibly passed through to the client.

```
SELECT
            O.ORDER_ID orderId,
            O.ORDER_NAME orderName,
            O.ACTIVE_START orderDate,
            (SELECT
                OI.ORDER_ITEM_ID itemId,
                OI.NAME name,
                OI.COMMENTS comments
            FROM
                dbo.ORDER_ITEM OI
            WHERE
                O.ORDER_ID = OI.ORDER_ID
            FOR JSON PATH) items
        FROM
            dbo.[ORDER] O
        WHERE
            O.PERSON_ID = @PERSON_ID
        FOR JSON PATH;
```

Which would return something like

```
[
  {
    "orderId": 21,
    "orderName": "my first order",
    "orderDate": "2016-09-18T11:01:41",
    "items": [
      {
        "itemId": 41,
        "name": "pizza",
        "comments": "Extra Cheese Please"
      },
      {
        "itemId": 42,
        "name": "italian sandwich",
        "comments": "No peppers"
      }
    ]
  }
]...
```

There is a git project that has wrappers around ado for facilitating these kinds of calls at https://github.com/ahhsoftware/EzAdoVSSolution which might be something you'd be interested in.